# how to give height and width video on web view in android(different different device)?

Tags: android, html, android-webview, android-websettings

I want give size height and width programmatically inside on webview and i'm using following code :-

```
    width = (int) (display.getWidth() / 1.25);
    height = (int) (display.getWidth() / 1.25);

String html = "<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" "
            + "style=\"border: 0; width:" + width + "; height:" + height
            + ";" + "padding:0px; margin:0namepx\" "
            + "id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" "
            + "src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoId
            + "?fs=0\" frameborder=\"0\" " + "allowfullscreen autobuffer "
            + "controls onclick=\"this.play()\">\n" + "</iframe>\n";
```

**now how is it seen on emulator**

**480*800 WVGA (mdpi)**

see the video height and width

[image]

**720*1280 xhpdi**

see the video height and width

[image]

i m stuck then how to give size programatically on webview content (image and video).

and im used almost all kind of function and methods but still same problem.